# Unable to persist child class records using spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

## Problem

1)I created a class employee that extends Person.I can persist employee records and not person.

**Solution I implemented**

1)Created modal classes Employee and Person.

## Modal Classes

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee",
    indexes = {@Index(name = "username", columnList = "username", unique = true)})
public class BaseEmployee extends Person {

public static final String OBJECT_KEY = "EMPLOYEE";
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
// Who created this baseEmployee
private String userId;
//    @Indexed(unique = true)
private String username;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ROLE role;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private STATUS status;
private String designation;
```

## Person

```
public class Person extends AbstractEntity {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String contact;
private String email;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private GENDER gender;
private String imageId;
private String address;
private String locationId;
private DateTime dob;
private double[] location;
private String pinCode;
```

## Employee Controller

```
@PostMapping
ApiResponse<BaseEmployee> post(@RequestBody CreateEntry<BaseEmployee> baseEmployeeCreateEntry) {
    BaseEmployee baseEmployeeToCreate = baseEmployeeCreateEntry.getEntry();
    baseEmployeeToCreate.setStatus(STATUS.ACTIVE);
    baseEmployeeToCreate = employeeService.post(baseEmployeeToCreate);
    if (baseEmployeeToCreate != null)
        authenticationService.setPassword(baseEmployeeToCreate, baseEmployeeCreateEntry.getPassword());
    return ApiResponse.success().message("Created Successfully!").object(baseEmployeeToCreate);
}

public class CreateEntry<T> {
private T entry;
private String password;
```

## Service

```
@Override
public <E extends BaseEmployee> E post(E employee) {
    employee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
    System.out.println(employee);
    LOG.info("Admin data" + employee);
    LOG.info("PUT employee {} {} {}", employee.getId(), employee.getFirstName(), employee.getEmail());
    return employee;
}
```

## Repository

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<BaseEmployee, Long> {}

#Expected Output
 The Employee class Columns and Person class Columns

#Output Shown

mysql> select * from employee;

 id | created_at    | created_by    | last_modified_at | last_modified_by | version | designation | role  | status | user_id | username |

  1 | 1519624346694 | anonymousUser |    1519624346694 | anonymousUser    |       0 | csdcs       | ADMIN | ACTIVE | string  | admin    |
  3 | 1519624856504 | anonymousUser |    1519624856504 | anonymousUser    |       0 | csdcs       | ADMIN | ACTIVE | string  | admin1   |
  4 | 1519626598478 | anonymousUser |    1519626598478 | anonymousUser    |       0 | csdcs       | ADMIN | ACTIVE | string  | admin2   |
```

> Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong.Thankx in advance?

Comment: Can you try adding @MappedSuperclass to Person entity?

Comment: @RameshFadatare Thankx it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding @MappedSuperclass to Person entity?

Comment: Sure, i always read reference document , here is link - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: If you are interested in reading java/j2ee design patterns then read my blogs on - https://ramesh-java-design-patterns.blogspot.in/